# Postman gRPC Request not available

Tags: postman

I'm trying to create a gRPC Request in Postman but it's greyed out with the message "You don't have permission to take this action". I'm running the latest version (v10.12). Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

[image]

To replicate the issue I create a new workspace and click the "new" button in the left hand navigation

[image]

Comment: Looks fine to me. Which system? Are you logged in? What are the exact reproduction steps?

Comment: I have the same issue.

Comment: @Destroy666 Windows 10. Yes I'm logged in. I've added the reproduction steps above. It's just clicking the "new" button in the left hand navigation

Comment: Looks like a bug then, I'd much rather recommend contacting their support than asking here. Still can't reproduxe personally, even with new workspace.

Comment: @Destroy666 Quicker solution here and answer available for everyone. Looks like an issue with the postman update. The solution was to reinstall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this exact issue. On my mac I fixed this by moving Postman to the Bin then reinstalling it.